# No database selected SQL=SELECT `session_id` FROM error in Joomla

Tags: php, sql, joomla

I have a main website created in Joomla that is working fine www.comnicate.com and I created a test site for the site using the database and I have changed the database credentials on the test site as follows

```
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
public $password = 'xxxxxxx';
public $db = 'comnicat_footertest';
```

I have checked whether they are correct and I am sure that they are, however on logging into the test site I am getting the following error

```
**Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: No database selected SQL=SELECT `session_id` FROM `44h_session` WHERE `session_id` = '86adea38967938afe93e5592ccb226f8' LIMIT 0, 1**
```

I have googled for possible answers but I couldn't locate one as of now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This indicates the database name is incorrect.

Comment: I have rechecked again but all the database and usernames, passwords are correct in mysql.

Answer (score 2):

Check access rights for database user (SHOW GRANTS). I bet you don't have access rights to your database.

Answer (score 0):

This usually means you haven't changed the tmp/ and log/ path values in your configuration.php file.  Open the file in a text editor and change the values to reflect the full path from root to the respective folders in the new Joomla website.

Comment: I have done this as well but I still get the same error. I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: can you post you configuration file for the new Joomla instance?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and checked all different suggestions.
In fact , I encountered two different cases, both related with configuration.php error.
1- development site's operating system was windows and production site's was unix. The database names in windows are not case sensitive and in unix are case sensitive.
2- For connecting to database of local site you may need to use credentials of the root user of mysql, but in production site (especially if it is a non-dedicated host) you'll use database specific credentials.